# Ubuntu not using full resolution of LCD after switching to Unity from Ubuntu Classic

Tags: 11.04, unity

I had been using Ubuntu Classic with 11.04 for sometime. I tried switching to Unity and found that it doesnt use the full LCD. Theres a "black border" or unused portion of my LCD although the resolution remains at 1920x1080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! I solved the problem by installing the latest driver by ATI/AMD.

Comment: Oh but it keeps crashing ...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend opening up the monitors app. You should be able to adapt the monitor settings there.

Comment: I see nothing useful there ... resolution is at 1920x1080 but Ubuntu is not using the full screen...

Comment: jiewmeng can you post a screenshot or provide details of your hardware - it may be helpful to find a solution.